# Nav-links clickable but not visible in Mobile View

Tags: html, css, media-queries

[The screenshot of the error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9SIvq.jpg) The nav-links in mobile view do not appear but are clickable. New to HTML and CSS. The Ham-burger menu has z-index 1 it appears correctly. But the content of the menu do not appear. This error is in mobile view only. Attached media query code in css. The name of the stylesheet is different from that in my pc so that isn't an issue.

**HTML code**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
    <meta charset= "UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>Executive Committee</title>
    <link href="lib/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link href="style2.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <style>
     
        .our-team{
            padding: 30px 0 40px;
            background: #fff;
            overflow: hidden;
            position: relative;
            
        }
        .our-team .pic{
            width: 130px;
            height: 130px;
            margin-bottom: 50px;
            position: relative;
            z-index: 1;
           margin: auto;
          
        }

        .our-team .pic:before{
            content:"";
            width: 100%;
            background: #004165;
            position: absolute;
            bottom: 135%;
            right: 0;
            left: 0;
            transform: scale(3);
            transition: all 0.3s linear 0s;
        }

        .our-team:hover .pic:before{
            height: 100%;
        }

        .our-team .pic:after{
            content: "";
            width: 100%;
            height: 100%;
            border-radius: 50%;
            background: #004165;
            position: absolute;
            top: 0;
            left: 0;
            z-index: -1;
        }

        .our-team .pic img{
            width: 100%;
            height: auto;
            border-radius: 50%;
            transform: scale(1);
            transition: all 0.9s ease 0s;
        }
        .our-team:hover .pic img{
            box-shadow: 0 0 0 14px #f7f5ec;
            transform: scale(0.7);
        }

        .our-team .team-content{
            padding-top: 30px;
            margin-bottom: 30px;
        }

        .our-team .title{
            font-size: 22px;
            font-weight: 700;
            color: #4e5052;
            letter-spacing: 1px;
            text-transform: capitalize;
            margin-bottom: 5px;
            padding: 10px 10px 10px 10px;
        }

        .our-team .post{
            display: block;
            font-size: 15px;
            color: #4e5052;
            text-transform: capitalize;
            padding: 10px 10px 10px 10px;
        }

        .our-team .social{
            width: 100%;
            padding: 0;
            margin: 0;
            background: #004165;
            position: absolute;
            bottom: -100px;
            left: 0;
            transition: all 0.5s ease;
        }

        .our-team:hover .social{
            bottom: 0;
        }


        .our-team .social li{
            display: inline-block;
        }
        .our-team .social li a{
            display: block;
            padding: 10px;
            font-size: 17px;
            color: #fff;
            transition: all 0.3s ease 0s;
        }

        .our-team .social li a:hover{
            color: #eb1768;
            background: #f7f5ec;
            text-decoration: none;
        }

    </style>
</head>
<body>


    <nav>
        <div class="logo">
          <img src="images/TMxAU.png" alt="">
      </div>
        <div class="hamburger">
          <div class="line"></div>
          <div class="line"></div>
          <div class="line"></div>
        </div>
        <ul class="nav-links">
          <li><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Club Etiquette</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Achievements</a></li>
          <li><a href="exec.html">Executive Committee</a></li>
          <li><a href="pathways.html">Pathways</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Resources</a></li>
        </ul>
      </nav>
  
      <section class="landing">
        <div>Alone we can do so little, together we can do so much.</div>
      </section>
  
      <script src="app.js"></script>

      <section class="pathwayarea">
        <div class="container">
        
            <!-- Page Heading -->
            <h1 class="my-4">Team</h1>




    <br><br>
<section class="">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-4 col-sm-6 mb-4">
                <div class="our-team">
                    <div class="pic">
                        <img src ="images\Team\1.png">
                    </div>
                    <div class="team-content">
                        <h3 class ="title">ABCD/h3>
                        <span class="post">Role1</span>
                    </div>
                    <ul class="social">
                        <li><a href = "" class="fa fa-facebook"></a></li>
                        <li><a href = "" class="fa fa-twitter"></a></li>
                        <li><a href = "" class="fa fa-instagram"></a></li>
                        <li><a href = "" class="fa fa-linkedin"></a></li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>



            <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-4 col-sm-6 mb-4">
                <div class="our-team">
                    <div class="pic">
                        <img src ="images\Team\2.png">
                    </div>
                    <div class="team-content">
                        <h3 class ="title">ABCD</h3>
                        <span class="post">Role2</span>
                    </div>
                    <ul class="social">
                        <li><a href = "" class="fa fa-facebook"></a></li>
                        <li><a href = "" class="fa fa-twitter"></a></li>
                        <li><a href = "" class="fa fa-instagram"></a></li>
                        <li><a href = "" class="fa fa-linkedin"></a></li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-4 col-sm-6 mb-4">
                <div class="our-team">
                    <div class="pic">
                        <img src ="images\Team\3.png">
                    </div>
                    <div class="team-content">
                        <h3 class ="title">ABCD</h3>
                        <span class="post">Role3</span>
                    </div>
                    <ul class="social">
                        <li><a href = "" class="fa fa-facebook"></a></li>
                        <li><a href = "" class="fa fa-twitter"></a></li>
                        <li><a href = "" class="fa fa-instagram"></a></li>
                        <li><a href = "" class="fa fa-linkedin"></a></li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-4 col-sm-6 mb-4">
                <div class="our-team">
                    <div class="pic">
                        <img src ="images\Team\4.png">
                    </div>
                    <div class="team-content">
                        <h3 class ="title">ABCD</h3>
                        <span class="post">Role5</span>
                    </div>
                    <ul class="social">
                        <li><a href = "" class="fa fa-facebook"></a></li>
                        <li><a href = "" class="fa fa-twitter"></a></li>
                        <li><a href = "" class="fa fa-instagram"></a></li>
                        <li><a href = "" class="fa fa-linkedin"></a></li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
        
            <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-4 col-sm-6 mb-4">
                <div class="our-team">
                    <div class="pic">
                        <img src ="images\Team\6.png">
                    </div>
                    <div class="team-content">
                        <h3 class ="title">ABCD</h3>
                        <span class="post">Role6</span>
                    </div>
                    <ul class="social">
                        <li><a href = "" class="fa fa-facebook"></a></li>
                        <li><a href = "" class="fa fa-twitter"></a></li>
                        <li><a href = "" class="fa fa-instagram"></a></li>
                        <li><a href = "" class="fa fa-linkedin"></a></li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-4 col-sm-6 mb-4">
                <div class="our-team">
                    <div class="pic">
                        <img src ="images\Team\7.png">
                    </div>
                    <div class="team-content">
                        <h3 class ="title">ABCD</h3>
                        <span class="post">Role7</span>
                    </div>
                    <ul class="social">
                        <li><a href = "" class="fa fa-facebook"></a></li>
                        <li><a href = "" class="fa fa-twitter"></a></li>
                        <li><a href = "" class="fa fa-instagram"></a></li>
                        <li><a href = "" class="fa fa-linkedin"></a></li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-4 col-sm-6 mb-4">
                <div class="our-team">
                    <div class="pic">
                        <img src ="images\Team\8.png">
                    </div>
                    <div class="team-content">
                        <h3 class ="title">ABCD</h3>
                        <span class="post">Role8</span>
                    </div>
                    <ul class="social">
                        <li><a href = "" class="fa fa-facebook"></a></li>
                        <li><a href = "" class="fa fa-twitter"></a></li>
                        <li><a href = "" class="fa fa-instagram"></a></li>
                        <li><a href = "" class="fa fa-linkedin"></a></li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
            
            
            <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-4 col-sm-6 mb-4">
                <div class="our-team">
                    <div class="pic">
                        <img src ="images\Team\9.png">
                    </div>
                    <div class="team-content">
                        <h3 class ="title">ABCD</h3>
                        <span class="post">Role9</span>
                    </div>
                    <ul class="social">
                        <li><a href = "" class="fa fa-facebook"></a></li>
                        <li><a href = "" class="fa fa-twitter"></a></li>
                        <li><a href = "" class="fa fa-instagram"></a></li>
                        <li><a href = "" class="fa fa-linkedin"></a></li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>

        </div>
    </div>
</section>  
</div>
</section>







    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</body>
<footer id="footer">
    <div class="footer-top">
      <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
    
          <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-6 footer-info">
            <h3>Club Name Here</h3>
            <p>ABCD</p>
          </div>
    
          <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-6 footer-links">
            <h4>Useful Links</h4>
            <ul>
              <li><i class="ion-ios-arrow-right"></i> <a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
              <li><i class="ion-ios-arrow-right"></i> <a href="#">Club Etiquette</a></li>
              <li><i class="ion-ios-arrow-right"></i> <a href="#">Achievements</a></li>
              <li><i class="ion-ios-arrow-right"></i> <a href="#">Executive Committee</a></li>
              <li><i class="ion-ios-arrow-right"></i> <a href="pathways.html">Pathways</a></li>
              <li><i class="ion-ios-arrow-right"></i> <a href="#">Resources</a></li>
            </ul>
          </div>
    
          <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-6 footer-contact">
            <h4>Contact Us</h4>
            <p>Contact Text here/p>
    
            <div class="social-links">
              <a href="#" class="twitter"><i class="fa fa-twitter"></i></a>
              <a href="#" class="facebook"><i class="fa fa-facebook"></i></a>
              <a href="#" class="instagram"><i class="fa fa-instagram"></i></a>
              <a href="#" class="linkedin"><i class="fa fa-linkedin"></i></a>
            </div>
          </div>
                <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-6 footer-newsletter">
            <h4>Interested in learning more?</h4>
            <p>Drop us your E-Mail ID and we'll get in touch with you.</p>
            <form action="" method="post">
              <input type="email" name="email"><input type="submit"  value="Submit">
            </form>
          </div>
    
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    
    
    </footer>
</html>
```

**CSS code**

```
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;[enter image description here][1]
  }
  body {
    font-family: sans-serif;
  }
 
  nav {
    height: 10vh;
  }
  
  .nav-links {
    display: flex;
    list-style: none;
    width: 50%;
    height: 100%;
    justify-content: space-around;
    align-items: center;
    margin-left: auto;
  }
  
  .pathwayarea{
    background: #a9b2b1;
    padding-top: 10px;
 
}
  .nav-links li a {
    color: #000;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 16px;
    font-weight: bold;
    padding: 5px 20px;
  }
  
  .nav-links li a:hover{
    background: #772432;
  color: #fff;
  }
  
  
  
  .landing {
    height: 90vh;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
      width: inherit;
    align-items: center;
    background: linear-gradient(0deg, rgba(242,223,116,1) 55%, rgba(255,255,255,1) 100%);
   
    
  }
  .container h1{
    text-align: center;
    font-weight: bold;
    color: #000;
}

  .logo img{
    width: 300px;
    float: left;
    height: auto;
    margin-top: 10px;
    margin-left: 30px;
}


.landing div{
  top: 50%;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
  text-align: center;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 3rem;
}



  #footer {
    background: #000;
    padding: 0 0 30px 0;
    color: #eee;
    font-size: 14px;
    }
    
    #footer .footer-top {
    background: #111;
    padding: 60px 0 30px 0;
    }
    
    #footer .footer-top .footer-info {
    margin-bottom: 30px;
    }
    
    #footer .footer-top .footer-info h3 {
    font-size: 34px;
    margin: 0 0 20px 0;
    padding: 2px 0 2px 10px;
    line-height: 1;
    font-family: "Myriad Pro";
    font-weight: 700;
    letter-spacing: 3px;
    border-left: 4px solid #cd202c;
    }
    
    #footer .footer-top .footer-info p {
    font-size: 14px;
    line-height: 24px;
    margin-bottom: 0;
    font-family: "Montserrat", sans-serif;
    color: #fff;
    }
    
    #footer .footer-top .social-links a {
    font-size: 18px;
    display: inline-block;
    background: #333;
    color: #eee;
    line-height: 1;
    padding: 8px 0;
    margin-right: 4px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    text-align: center;
    width: 36px;
    height: 36px;
    transition: 0.3s;
    }
    
    #footer .footer-top .social-links a:hover {
    background: #fff;
    color: #fff;
    }
    
    #footer .footer-top h4 {
    font-size: 14px;
    font-weight: bold;
    color: #fff;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    position: relative;
    padding-bottom: 12px;
    }
    
    #footer .footer-top h4::before,
    #footer .footer-top h4::after {
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    height: 2px;
    }
    
    #footer .footer-top h4::before {
    right: 0;
    background: #555;
    }
    
    #footer .footer-top h4::after {
    background: #cd202c;
    width: 60px;
    }
    
    #footer .footer-top .footer-links {
    margin-bottom: 30px;
    }
    
    #footer .footer-top .footer-links ul {
    list-style: none;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    }
    
    #footer .footer-top .footer-links ul i {
    padding-right: 8px;
    color: #ddd;
    }
    
    #footer .footer-top .footer-links ul li {
    border-bottom: 1px solid #333;
    padding: 10px 0;
    font-family: "Myriad Pro";
    }
    
    #footer .footer-top .footer-links ul li:first-child {
    padding-top: 0;
    }
    
    #footer .footer-top .footer-links ul a {
    color: #eee;
    }
    
    #footer .footer-top .footer-links ul a:hover {
    color: #fff;
    }
    
    #footer .footer-top .footer-contact {
    margin-bottom: 30px;
    font-family: "Myriad Pro";
    }
    
    #footer .footer-top .footer-contact p {
    line-height: 26px;
    font-family: "Myriad Pro";
    }
    
    #footer .footer-top .footer-newsletter {
    margin-bottom: 30px;
    font-family: "Myriad Pro";
    }
    
    #footer .footer-top .footer-newsletter input[type="email"] {
    border: 0;
    padding: 6px 8px;
    width: 65%;
    font-family: "Myriad Pro";
    }
    
    #footer .footer-top .footer-newsletter input[type="submit"] {
    background: #cd202c;
    border: 0;
    width: 35%;
    padding: 6px 0;
    text-align: center;
    color: #fff;
    transition: 0.3s;
    cursor: pointer;
    font-family: "Myriad Pro";
    }
    
    
    
    
    
    
    
    
    
    @media screen and (max-width: 768px) {
   
      
  .landing div{
    width: auto;
    height: auto;
    max-width: 100%;
    max-height: 100%;
  }
  .landing {
    
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
   
    
  }
  .landing img{
    width: auto;
    height: auto;
    max-width: 100%;
    max-height: 100%;
  }
    .line {
      width: 30px;
      height: 3px;
      background: #000;
      margin: 5px;
        padding-left: 5px;
    }
    nav {
      position: relative;
    }
  
    .hamburger {
      position: absolute;
      cursor: pointer;
      right: 5%;
      top: 50%;
      transform: translate(-5%, -50%);
      z-index: 3;
    }
  
    .nav-links {
      position: fixed;
      background: #f2df74;
      height: 100vh;
      width: 100%;
      flex-direction: column;
      clip-path: circle(100px at 90% -10%);
      -webkit-clip-path: circle(100px at 90% -19%);
      transition: all 1s ease-out;
      pointer-events: none;
  
    }
    .nav-links.open {
      clip-path: circle(1000px at 90% -10%);
      -webkit-clip-path: circle(1000px at 90% -10%);
      pointer-events: all;
      z-index: 2;
    }
    .landing {
     
    }
    .nav-links li {
      opacity: 0;
    }
    .nav-links li a {
      font-size: 25px;
    }
    .nav-links li:nth-child(1) {
      transition: all 0.5s ease 0.2s;
    }
    .nav-links li:nth-child(2) {
      transition: all 0.5s ease 0.4s;
    }
    .nav-links li:nth-child(3) {
      transition: all 0.5s ease 0.6s;
    }
    .nav-links li:nth-child(4) {
      transition: all 0.5s ease 0.6s;
    }
    .nav-links li:nth-child(5) {
      transition: all 0.5s ease 0.6s;
    }
    .nav-links li:nth-child(6) {
      transition: all 0.5s ease 0.6s;
    }
    li.fade {
      opacity: 1;
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

First, a few observations:

- You are using different versions of Bootstrap: in CSS: `4.3.1` and JS: `3.3.7`.
- The footer is in the wrong place, you need to place it before closing the `</body>` tag.
- As you are using Bootstrap why not use the [navbar](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.5/components/navbar/)?

To fix your problem just remove the opacity from `.nav-links li` or set to 1:

```css
.nav-links li {
  opacity: 1;
}
```

EDIT:

Add this to the respective classes:

```css
  .nav-links {
    visibility: hidden;
    opacity: 0;
    z-index: 1;
  }

  .nav-links.open {
    opacity: 1;
    visibility: visible;
  }
```

And remove this:

```css
  .nav-links li {
    opacity: 0;
  }

  li.fade {
    opacity: 1;
  }
```

Now it should work as expected.

Working example: [Codepen](https://codepen.io/demartini/pen/xxZLoRb).

Comment: Tried the above solution but they appear in a transition and disappear. Fixed the footer tag. Is there any other way to solve this before I try using navbar in bootstrap? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Could you provide me your javascript too?